# How did removal of the gi affect contemporary MMA?

Tags: judo, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, mixed-martial-arts, gi

Did it remove an advantage for BJJ and Judo players?  If so, can it be said to have beneficial for those arts, forcing the competitors to do what they do with having a tool?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. You are asking whether removing the gi in MMA is good for BJJ and judo in MMA?

Comment: @mattm I asking about how eliminating wearing of the Gi has affected the contemporary sport of MMA, compared to the early days (Royce Gracie utilized it quite effectively as a tool.)  But also asking if that removal of a potential tool for BJJ practitioners and Judoka required them to "up their games", which would I'd assume would be beneficial for those arts overall.